# FFmpeg converted mp4 file fails to load in Quicktime

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime

I've been using FFmpeg to convert a movie I need to play in MP4, however in Quicktime the following error is presented;

[image: FFmpeg file produces this Quicktime error]

(Error -2041: an invalid sample description was found in the movie (output.mp4)).

I used the following FFmpeg command parameters to convert the file;

> C:\Temp\EOBTemp>ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y
>   -acodec libmp3lame -ab 96k -vcodec libx264 -vpre lossless_slow -crf 22
>   -threads 0 output.mp4

Now this file plays absolutely fine, in Windows Media Player, and VideoLAN (FFmpeg based, so no surprise here.  I using the latest build from [HawkEye's FFmpeg Windows Builds](http://hawkeye.arrozcru.org/)
(FFmpeg git-a304071 32-bit Static (Latest)).

I really hope this isn't a AAC problem, as I've been trying to get FFmpeg to use the libfaac.dll library (in the same folder as the FFmpeg.exe) with the command;

> -acodec libfaac

Help!  I'm at a loss!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using "-acodec aac" instead?

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked after adding -strict experimental to the params

Answer (score 2):

Quicktime player doesn't like mp3 encoded audio in an mp4 video. Using aac as audio codes solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

`ffmpeg -i "file.flv" -f mov -vcodec libx264 -b 4096k -acodec libmp3lame -ab 256k "file.mov"`